# Backlight control doesn't work in Manjaro with nVidia GF108GLM [NVS5200M]

Tags: nvidia, laptop, manjaro, brightness

I have just scrapped Linux Mint 16 for Manjaro (kernel 4.1.15) on my Dell Latitude 6530. I have installed NVidia proprietary drivers in the hope resume from hibernate would work. It does but now I'm facing other issues, such as brightness control.

I've checked [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight) for a solution and the only option they give is xorg-xbacklight. Unfortunately it doesn't work either.

I've tried writing values to `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` but brightness doesn't change. Indeed, as hinted in the Wiki, the ACPI value changes but brightness doesn't. I then tried xbacklight but still no change.

**EDIT**: I have also tried keeping the [native brightness control] with kernel argument `video.use_native_backlight=1`. Still no luck... except that backlight seems to have gotten dimmer. Coincidentally I had set `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` to 50% before rebooting my laptop.

I know brightness control *does* work because it did with Linux Mint 16 — ok, that was a rather old kernel, i.e. 3.11 or something. NVidia drivers were also the proprietary ones, version 304.

Any hint or suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backlight issue seems to have many potential sources. Mine was just about enabling backlight control with nVidia proprietary driver in Xorg configuration. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/199652) on Ubuntu stack exchange did the trick:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    ...
    # Added the following option:
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

After login out and then back, backlight control keys worked like a charm.